Can a Brahmana become a Mleccha?
I am born in a Brahmana family.Yesterday I said I am muslim twice to for some analysis as to how a Muslim would react to certain situation.After that I behaved like a normal hindu..i.e taking Lord's name etc..there is an instance in Mahabharata where King Yayati curses his son that his descendants will become mlecchas.Also there are some instances in Mahabharata where Kshatriya tribes have descended to the level of mlecchas.My question is "according to scriptures":
1.Can a Brahmana descend to the level of a Mleccha or only Kshatriyas and others?
2.Is becoming a Mleccha final?
3.Can Aryans who have descended to mlecchatva revert to Dharma(are there any instances in scriptures?
a.After converting in this life.
b.After many generations have have become mlecchas?(according to scriptures..of course there are many organisations who convert muslims and christians back to hinduism but is it scripturally valid?)
4.If not what sadhana can a mleccha do according to scriptures?
5.Can a mleccha do bhakti?
Please answer this in the light of scriptures..thanks
